# ¿Cómo formateo una cadena al estilo printf, pero para guardarla en una variable en C?

Tags: c

Algo como:

```
char *a = "Hola";
printf("%s",a);
```

Pero ese formato guardarlo en una variable.

Comment: ¿Te refieres a guardar el formato en una variable o te refieres a guardar el texto formateado en una variable?

Comment: Guardar el texto formateado en una variable para después usarlo

Comment: utiliza: sprintf que devuelve el texto formateado. Perdón no devuelve el texto formateado sino que su primer parametro es la variable donde quieres poner el texto formateado.  ` sprintf(miVar,"%s",a),`

Comment: Gracias, si ya me di cuenta

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La función `printf` es una función de impresión (`print`) con formato (`f`ormat) y [tiene tres variantes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf):

- `printf`: Imprime en la salida estándar (consola).
- `fprintf`: Imprime en el flujo de datos (`f`ile `print` `f`ormat) facilitado como primer parámetro.
- `sprintf`: Imprime en el puntero facilitado (`s`tring `print` `f`ormat) como primer parámetro.

Por lo tanto, necesitas usar `sprintf`:

```
char *a = "Hola";
char mensaje[100];
sprintf(mensaje, "%s", a); // Imprime en 'mensaje'
```